# How Can I Upload Blob Video With Camera in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, blob

I'm recording video using html5 and getting blob code (blob:http://localhost:3000/e359696c-b126-4382-bcc3-eaa1db01f322)
I want to upload this video to the server with node.js. How can I do it?

Html5 Codes

```
media_recorder.addEventListener('stop', function() {
    let video_local = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(blobs_recorded, { type: 'video/webm' }));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cam',
        data: {video:video_local},
    })
});
```

Node.js Codes:

```
router.post('/save',(req,res)=>{
    fs.writeFile('Camera.webm', req.body.video, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
            res.status(500).send('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('ok');
        }
    });
})
```

Thank you for your helpful